# Programmatically login on a different domain using same Symfony 2/3 project DB

Tags: symfony, session

I have a single Symfony project. But it manages N domains used by final customers, so we can have different brands & policies. On another domain we can access to the backoffice views of the project.
On the customers view we’d like to impersonate our customers on their corresponding domain.

My strategy is

When a staff user logs in any of our domains, I want to automatically & silently  logging on the other domains. So when a button redirects to another domain/?_username=XXX  , there will no login to be made.

My incomplete implementation is
-  listen the login_succes,
- get the username and password from the request
- call to an api

```
$data['_username'] = $req->request->get('username');
    $data['_password'] = $req->request->get('password');
    $response = $this->client->post(‘thedomain/noauth/login', [
        'form_params' => $data,
            ]
    );
```

that if possible ( I don’t know) should be able to log on its domain with this browser.

I don’t know if it can be achieved using the JWT token I create in the API endpoint and change the security config for admin firewall area, or maybe I need to simulate a complete login there using UserNamePasswordToken.

Maybe I should not rely on the endpoint Request object .

```
$jwt = $this->get('lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_manager');
$jwt_token = $jwt->create($user);
 $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'firewallname', $user->getRoles());
$this->get("security.token_storage")->setToken($token);
$session = $request->getSession();
$session->set('_security_main', serialize($token));
```

In addition I don’t know if there is some more work in order to store a cookie on the browser.

Many doubts, so your help would be really appreciated in order to reduce my testing time.

**UPDATE**

Trying the blast solution (see answer 1), when I run composer require  "blast-project/doctrine-session-bundle" I get this error:

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for blast-project/doctrine-session-bundle ^0.1.0 -> satisfiable by blast-project/doctrine-session-bundle[0.1].
    - blast-project/doctrine-session-bundle 0.1 requires blast-project/base-entities-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by blast-project/base-entities-bundle[dev-master] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

so I add this line temporarily to my composer.json
 "minimum-stability": "dev" but still get error, not SF3-friendly?:

```
  Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v3.2.4, 2.8.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[2.8.x-dev, v3.2.4].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[2.8.x-dev, v3.2.4].
    - blast-project/core-bundle dev-master requires symfony/symfony 2.8.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[2.8.x-dev].
    - blast-project/base-entities-bundle dev-master requires blast-project/core-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by blast-project/core-bundle[dev-master].
    - blast-project/doctrine-session-bundle 0.1 requires blast-project/base-entities-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by blast-project/base-entities-bundle[dev-master].
    - Installation request for blast-project/doctrine-session-bundle ^0.1.0 -> satisfiable by blast-project/doctrine-session-bundle[0.1].
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony (locked at v3.2.4, required as 3.*) -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.2.4].
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just store your sessions in the shared database since it is shared you have no implementation to do you just store the session in db symfony will set a cookie by itself and then when you access other servers they can read this cookie since they read the session data from the same db.

Here is the bundle i used to do exactly that: https://github.com/blast-project/doctrine-session-bundle

And the project where i did it: 
https://github.com/libre-informatique/LIBioSymfonyProject/commit/36493dd815c907338b0730fa7d5e2f3ef1654a6a

Comment: It sounds great, but under SF3 I'm not able to composer require, or install the library....
I update the question including the error...

Comment: I will try to update the readme of the bundle to include easy install instructions this weekend